# entity can not be null?

Tags: java, tapestry

I wanted to retrieve found object or a null from a database.

In my ProjectFollowerImpl, for a method useFollowingProject I return a single instance that matches the query, or null if the query returns no results.

```
@Override
public ProjectFollower userFollowingProject(Integer userId, Integer projectId) {
    return (ProjectFollower) session.createCriteria(classType)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("user.id", userId))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("project.id", projectId))
            .uniqueResult();
}
```

Then in a tapestry page, I have following methods:

```
public ProjectFollower getUserFollowingProject() {
    return projectFollowerDao.userFollowingProject(loggedInUser.getId(), project.getId());
}

@CommitAfter
void onActionFromFollowProject() {
    ProjectFollower pf = getUserFollowingProject();
    if (pf != null) {
        projectFollowerDao.delete(pf.getId());
    } else {
        pf = new ProjectFollower();
        pf.setProjectId(project);
        pf.setUserId(loggedInUser);
        projectFollowerDao.merge(pf);
    }
}
```

However, tapestry throws null pointer exception, stack trace:

```
com.rile.issuetracker.pages.Tracker getUserFollowingProject()   Tracker.java    75
com.rile.issuetracker.pages.Tracker advised$onActionFromFollowProject_6d8b9673baf() Tracker.java    80
```

So why is it a problem to return a null value for a object?  What am I doing wrong ?

**UPDATE:**

```
public class Tracker {

@Property
@SessionState
private User loggedInUser;

@Property
@Inject
private ProjectDao projectDao;
@Property
private Project projectP1, project;
@Property
private List<Project> projectList;
@Property
@Inject
private ProjectFollowerDao projectFollowerDao;

@Property
@Inject
private TicketDao ticketDao;
@Property
private List<Ticket> ticketList;
@Property
private Ticket ticketP1;
@Property
@Inject
private TicketFollowerDao ticketFollowerDao;

@Property
private Util util = new Util();

public boolean getLoggedIn() {
    return loggedInUser.getEmail() != null;
}    

@PageLoaded
void onPageLoad() {
    projectList = projectDao.loadAll();
    ticketList = ticketDao.loadAll();
}

void onActivate(Integer contextValue) {
    if (contextValue != null) {  
        project = projectDao.getByID(contextValue);
    }
    if (project != null) {
        List ticketListByProjectID = ticketDao.getTicketsByProjectID(project.getId());
        if (!ticketListByProjectID.isEmpty()) {
            ticketList = ticketListByProjectID;
        } else {
            ticketList = null;
        }
    }
}

public ProjectFollower getUserFollowingProject() {
        return projectFollowerDao.userFollowingProject(loggedInUser.getId(), project.getId());        

}

@CommitAfter
void onActionFromFollowProject() {
    ProjectFollower pf = getUserFollowingProject();
    if (pf != null) {
        projectFollowerDao.delete(pf.getId());
    } else {
        pf = new ProjectFollower();
        pf.setProjectId(project);
        pf.setUserId(loggedInUser);
        projectFollowerDao.merge(pf);
    }
}

public boolean getIsUserFollowingTicket() {
    return ticketFollowerDao.isUserFollowingTicket(loggedInUser.getId(), ticketP1.getId());
}

@CommitAfter
void onActionFromFollowTicket() {}

public String getActiveFor(String parameter) {
    if (parameter == null || parameter.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    switch (parameter) {
        case "userFollowingProject":
            return getUserFollowingProject() != null ? "active" : "null";
        case "userFollowingTicket":
            return getIsUserFollowingTicket() ? "anchor-active" : "anchor-inactive";
        default: 
            return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It is injected with @Inject annotaion. It works fine. I think I forgot this one, I should maybe try/catch this, I will try this in a moment

Comment: can you post completed code, and show how you populate `loggedInUser` and `project` variables? in any of them is null you might have NPE thrown

Comment: It all works fine, expect this method. But I will update my post now with complete code.

Comment: Can you please advice what is the variable - `projectFollowerDao` ? Seems like that is null.

Comment: @AnandSKumar It's is injected in declaration. It is not null.

Comment: I think this requires try/catch block, where do you suggest it is appropriate to use try/catch, in DAO or in page  ?

Answer (score 1):

From the complete code, it looks like the best bet is that project is null, after checking complete class, we see that its not injected, and its value is only set in `onActivate` function, if contextValue is not null and `projectDao.getByID(contextValue)` returns a non-null value.

Could you please confirm that is happenning correctly before the call to `onActionFromFollowProject`

Comment: I can confirm that, project is not null before I call onActionFromFollowProject.

Comment: I think try catch is the solution here, but I'm not sure where should I validate, in DAO or in Tracker page ?

Comment: Is something else null, can you debug or use `System.out.println` to check what is null , the only three things that can cause NPE are - `loggedInUser` , `project` and `projectFollowerDao`

Comment: Also , don't you need a getter/setter for the injected properties ?

Comment: No, bcs I'm using @Property.

Comment: I'm pretty sure loggedInUser is not null, only project or projectFollowerDao for some stupid reason, but I'll check. One moment please :).

Comment: Project is null. But why would it be null, when before calling onAction, everything it is initialised?

Comment: put println in `onActivate` before and after `project = ..` line, if they are getting printed, then that means `projectDao.getByID(contextValue)` is returning null for some reason, if not getting printed then that means contextValue is null.
Also , print contextValue along with it, maybe its value is not what you expected.

Comment: I did just like you said, I printed both contextValue and project object, they are not null at all. And they also print values that I expect.

Comment: How can I show this to you live ? Can we skype, sharescreen or something ?

Comment: Are you debugging this using some IDE? Sorry I do not have access to skype or sharescreen, max we can do is the stackoverflow chat , 
My guess is that the instance in which `onActivate` function is called and the instance for which the other function is called are different, could you please check if the scope of the component class is somehow causing this, if there is any such thing? If not, lets move this discussion to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80157/discussion-between-xerath-and-anand-s-kumar).